# Singleton Pattern - Symbols in shared library and dynamic loading

Tags: c++, linker, singleton, dynamic-loading

What are the differences between the following two versions of the Meyer's Singleton:

Variant A:

singleton.h

```
class Singleton {
  public:
  static Singleton& GlobalInstance();
}
```

singleton.cpp

```
Singleton &Singleton::GlobalInstance() {
  static Singleton* instance = new Singleton();
  return *instance;
}
```

Variant B (definition in header):

singleton.h

```
class Singleton {
  public:
  static Singleton& GlobalInstance() {
    static Singleton* instance = new Singleton();
    return *instance;
  }
}
```

When I create a shared library (gcc 9.2.1) which uses Variant A, I will get the following symbols:

```
T Singleton::GlobalInstance()
```

while with variant B I will get:

```
u guard variable for Singleton::GlobalInstance()::instance
W Singleton::GlobalInstance()
u Singleton::GlobalInstance()::instance
```

I'm trying to understand what the exact difference is here and when the compiler (gcc) will emit the code with the guard variable and what effect it has.

Using multiple shared libraries which use variant A or B, gives a different behaviour when dynamically loading them (e.g. variant A creates a new instance of the Singleton in each shared library while variant B will lead to a shared instance across the shared libraries as it is a weak symbol).

Shared library is produced in the following way:

test.cpp

```
#include "singleton.h"

void test() {
  Singleton::GlobalInstance();
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -fPIC -c test.cpp singleton.cpp
g++ -shared -o libtest.so test.o singleton.o
```

Comment: Variant B looks to be using threadsafe initialisation for `instance` while variant A is not.  Why that should be I don't know - I would have thought that both should do so, (from C++11 onwards) and indeed when I test your code at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/AXg46s), that's what I see.  It's all rather odd.

Comment: I'd advise to avoid singletons. They are just glorified global variables and tend to cause more trouble over time than they solve. The "singleton pattern" should in my opinion be renamed the "singleton *anti*pattern".

Comment: Yes, I can see the same behaviour that both get compiled thread safe, however when included and compiled to a shared library Variant A seems to lose this property.